# How to triple the quantity of ingredients in order to make 12 standard sized muffins?

Tags: recipe-scaling, muffins

I found an interesting recipe and I would like to triple it in order to make 12 standard sized muffins.

These are the ingredients and based on this recipe, it makes 4 muffins.

> 1/4 cup butter
>   1/4 cup semisweet chocolate chips
>   1 egg
>   1/4 cup sugar
>   1/4 teaspoon vanilla extract
>   1/4 cup all-purpose flour
>   1/4 cup chopped pecans

How can I triple the recipe and make twelve standard-sized muffins?r

Comment: I have an idea...what if I do the following ?   do the scaling in such a way...3/4 cup butter
3/4 cup semisweet chocolate chips
3 eggs
3/4 cup sugar
3/4 teaspoon vanilla extract
3/4 cup all-purpose flour
3/4 cup chopped pecans..............................................................................what do you think ? is it going to work like this and be successful ? I need some feedback as soon as possible. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yep. 3 x 4 = 12. Triple everything.

Answer (score 3):

Triple means "three time". Multiply all the ingredients by 3.

To double a recipe you would multiply everything by two.

To halve a recipe you would divide all ingredients by two.

(and so on)

Comment: This must be the most elementary answer I have seen on this site. Nothing more to say, really.